# Where is detective Tom hiding?

Tags: enigmatic-puzzle, cipher

Two detectives - Tom and Mark, are solving a murder mystery. They suspect that the murderer (or rather, the one who ordered the murder) is a very popular politician, Sean. So, they are secretly investigating the case.

One day, Mark receives this SMS on his phone, from Tom:

> Sean knows us. I'm Hiding. Open your door.

Mark opens his door, and finds a bag, full of dairy items and groceries. He searches the bag, and finds a notebook. The notebook is all new, and only one page has been written upon.

The page looks like the maths homework of a 7-year old student. It contains the following text:

> BASIC  MathematIcs
>
> ---
>
> 8+0=8
>   6/6=1
>   7-3=4
>   8x2=16
>   6+8=14
>   8-3=5
>   3+2=5
>   7-2=5
>   7x9=63
>   8/4=2
>   6+9=15
>   7-6=1
>   3-2=1
>   4x8=32
>   4+8=12
>   5+2=7

After going through this page, Mark understands where Tom is hiding.

So, where is Tom hiding, and how did Mark know this?

*P.S. This is my first puzzle on this site, and I am not very familiar with tags. So please correct the tags if you think I missed something*

Comment: Welcome to Puzzling! This seems like a pretty good puzzle, and you got the tags perfect. I hope I see you around here more! c:

Comment: Welcome; a nice start, clear, concise and interesting.

Comment: Thanks! I was used to reading the puzzles here. So today I decided to give you all a puzzle!

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Answer:

> P.Bird's Hotel, room number 004

Explanation:

> We look at the left side of equation as a 2-digit numbers (80,66,73,...).
>
>  Each of these numbers are the decimal code of Ascii character.
>
>  We get the text "PBIRDS HOTEL 004".
>
>  [Ascii Table](http://www.asciitable.com/)

Comment: Yes you are right! But there was one more hint in the line - `"BASIC MathematIcs"`. If you exclude the camel-case characters, the rest of the capitals can be arranged to form ASCII.